# pandasql will not import : ImportError: cannot import name to_sql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, pandasql

I installed pandasql with pip at the linux command prompt, and started ipython notebook:

```
felix@xanadu ~ $ sudo pip install pandasql
[sudo] password for felix: 
Downloading/unpacking pandasql
  Downloading pandasql-0.6.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/pandasql/setup.py) egg_info for package pandasql

Installing collected packages: pandasql
  Running setup.py install for pandasql

Successfully installed pandasql
Cleaning up...
felix@xanadu ~ $ ipython notebook
```

Then tried to import pandas and it in the ipython notebook:

```
import pandas    
import pandasql
```

..and it's not happy, have looked around but there doesn't seem to be an answer anywhere. Here is the error message it gave:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c9fa37159ca4> in <module>()
      1 import pandas
----> 2 import pandasql

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandasql/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .sqldf import sqldf
      2 import os
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 
      5 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandasql/sqldf.py in <module>()
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 from pandas.io.sql import to_sql, read_sql
      5 import re
      6 import os

ImportError: cannot import name to_sql
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Cheers

Comment: What version of `pandas` are you running?

Comment: `pandas.__version__`   returns   `'0.13.1'`

Comment: Probably upgrade to `0.16.0`?

Comment: Try upgrading, the current version is 0.16.0. I'm running that version, and don't have any issues with `from pandas.io.sql import to_sql, read_sql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely upgrade to `pandas` 0.16.0:

```
sudo pip install -U pandas
```

I just looked through the source code of `pandas/io/sql.py` in [0.13.1](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/d10a658673b7d2c2e7a346461c9a4bfc5233d7e1/pandas/io/sql.py) and [0.16.0](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/c91bdbadfdbf9f60879ead8dd86bd1e72ca18ccf/pandas/io/sql.py), and the `to_sql()` and `read_sql()` methods are not present in the older version, while they exist in the latest version.

---

To summarize our conversation in the comments, in order to successfully build `pandas`, you will need to install the `gcc`, `g++`, and `python-dev` packages from your system's package manager (`apt-get`, `yum`, `zypper`, whatever). If you are building for Python 3, the `python3-dev` package is needed.

If you are using Windows and the standard python.org version of Python, the easiest way to keep your packages up to date is to use Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages for Windows repository](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Many packages depend on his [MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl)-linked version of [`numpy`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy), including [`pandas`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas). The nice thing about all of these packages is that they are pre-compiled against both 32- and 64-bit versions of Python, and are generally available for Python 2.7, 3.3, and 3.4 (depending on the package, of course - some haven't been ported to Py3 yet). They are available in [`.whl`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide.html#installing-from-wheels) format, so installation/upgrading is as easy as

```
pip install -U name_of_package.whl
```

Comment: It won't :(  It runs when I put your command in and looks like it's working.. Downloading, extracting, creating all kinds of stuff. Then gives a couple of errors at the end:

Comment: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ipandas/src/klib -Ipandas/src -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c pandas/index.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/index.o

pandas/index.c:8:22: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory

 #include "pyconfig.h"

                      ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of pandas
Cleaning up...

Comment: @Felix what operating system are you running? At the minimum, you need to install the `python-dev` package from your package manager (`apt-get`, `yum`, whatever), as that is what supplies `pyconfig.h` and some other necessary files.

Comment: The operating system is Linux Mint 17.1 I think, but when I put in `uname -a` it gives Linux xanadu 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux . I took your advice and installed python-dev from the installer on the Mint gui. Then reran the panda upgrade command, which has yielded different errors this time.

Comment: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  Rolling back uninstall of pandas
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/pandas/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-jznXRo-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pandas

Comment: When I did this on Windows, I just installed Anaconda which brought over a lot of dependencies for scientific python.. Maybe should work out how to do that on Linux, I suspect that Mint installer installs one bit at a time and leaves important things out.

Comment: @Felix if you're not planning on building a lot of packages from scratch, then Anaconda might be the best way for you to go - they have a version for Linux. They're only at 0.15.2 for `pandas`, but that should work for this problem.

Comment: However, if you want to keep plugging ahead, try installing the `g++` package for compiling C++ code - that's what your latest error is complaining about.

Comment: Yes it definitely needed the g++ package. After that one was installed, pandas updated correctly to 0.16.0